# Spring Cloud Stream gcp PUB SUB java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream gcp pub sub and I got error from newrelic

This is stack trace from newrelic

Error message
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread**

```
java.lang.Thread.start0 (Native Method)

                                     java.lang.Thread.start (Thread.java:717)

          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)

            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1378)

                   io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolve (DnsNameResolver.java:252)

                   io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.refresh (DnsNameResolver.java:162)

    …ChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl.handleInternalSubchannelState (ManagedChannelImpl.java:981)

    …c.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl.access$4700 (ManagedChannelImpl.java:970)

    …ternal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl$1.onStateChange (ManagedChannelImpl.java:1018)

                  io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run (InternalSubchannel.java:320)

                     io.grpc.internal.ChannelExecutor.drain (ChannelExecutor.java:73)

    …InternalSubchannel$TransportListener.transportShutdown (InternalSubchannel.java:582)

    …c.netty.ClientTransportLifecycleManager.notifyShutdown (ClientTransportLifecycleManager.java:53)

    …etty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.goingAway (NettyClientHandler.java:641)

    …tty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.access$200 (NettyClientHandler.java:83)

    …ed.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$2.onGoAwayReceived (NettyClientHandler.java:230)

    …dler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection.goAwayReceived (DefaultHttp2Connection.java:232)

    …odec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.onGoAwayRead0 (DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:166)

    …tHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onGoAwayRead (DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:495)

    …ler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onGoAwayRead (Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:119)

    …er.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readGoAwayFrame (DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:591)

    …odec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState (DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:272)

    ….handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame (DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)

    ….handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame (Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)

    ….codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame (DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:118)

    …codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode (Http2ConnectionHandler.java:390)

    …etty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode (Http2ConnectionHandler.java:450)

    …ec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)

    …io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)

    …o.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)

    …hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)

    …hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)

    ….channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)

    …pc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap (SslHandler.java:1407)

    …ed.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible (SslHandler.java:1177)

    …pc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode (SslHandler.java:1221)

    …ec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)

    …io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)

    …o.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)

    …hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)

    …hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)

    ….channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)

    …channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead (DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)

    …hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)

    …hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)

    …o.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead (DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)

    ….channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read (AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)

    …d.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey (NioEventLoop.java:647)

    ….channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized (NioEventLoop.java:582)

    ….io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys (NioEventLoop.java:499)

    …rpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run (NioEventLoop.java:461)

    ….netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)

    …d.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run (FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)

                                       java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

As you see **io.grpc** spring cloud stream communicates to Pub/Sub via the gRPC protocol with thread pool.

Coding (Spring Cloud Stream) that I use for publishing data to GCP:

```
source.output().send(new GenericMessage<>(eventSync));
```

**ROOT CAUSE**

I found the problem caused by network issue (application cannot communicate to gcp pubsub as intended and the wait cause timeout and this made a bottleneck occur with the thread pool).

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

According the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_spring_cloud_gcp_for_pub_sub.html) I didn't set property `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.executor-threads and spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.publisher.executor-threads`

**QUESTION**

For Thread performace How to handle this problem in spring cloud stream?

It may help if I set `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.publisher.retry.total-timeout-seconds=5` (default is 0 that mean unlimit) ?

It may help if I set `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.publisher.retry.max-attempts=2` (default is 0 that mean unlimit) ?

It may help if I set `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.publisher.retry.max-rpc-timeout-second=5` (default is 0 that mean unlimit) ?

Comment: How many threads your application have? What's your nproc limit (`ulimit -n`) ?

Comment: @rkosegi ulimit -n = 65536

Comment: @rkosegi I have 400 thread